# An algebra $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra iff it is closed under countable increasing unions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a question that has been answered several times on here with the main answer generally revolving around defining an arbitrary collection of subsets $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subset A$, as well an associated increasing collection $\{B_i=\bigcup_{j=1}^iA_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$. By showing that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$, it has been concluded that $(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)\in A$.

My concern: in order to assume that $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is a subset of $A$, it necessarily must hold that $B_{i\to\infty}\in A$. However, this requires that $(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)\in A$; hence, the argument is circular. Is this an misunderstanding on my part? Or is there a reason we can assume $B_{i\to\infty}\in A$ for any increasing $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$?

Comment: There is nothing circular, it is just an equivalence. Either $A$ is closed under monotonic increasing unions or not. If it is closed then $A$ is a $\sigma$ algebra, otherwise it is not.

Comment: Saying a property holds for every finite $i$ doesn't imply it holds for the limit.

Comment: The equivalence happens under the assumption that $A$ is an algebra. This is, $A$ being an algebra is an assumption in both directions. That $B_i\in A$ follows from $A$ being an algebra. And just in case, in the notation $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ or in $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i$, the $i$ doesn't take the value $\infty$. They are understood as $1\leq i<\infty\wedge i\in\mathbb{Z}$. An interpretation that is at odds with $\bigcup_{i=1}^{3}B_i$, in which $i=3$ is included.